# PostgreSQL get array column value from second index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column that contains array of numbers like : ['1','3','45'];
And was looking for a way to select the column value from the second index so that I get ['3','45']

Is there any way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What data type is that column  exactly? `text[]`? `jsonb`? `json`?

Comment: [`col[2:]` should do](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)

Comment: The type is jsonb

Comment: So the value actually is `'["1", "3", "45"]'::jsonb`?